# Regular Expression to for Python nltk to split a Java application log into sentences

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to split a java application log into sentences using the Python nltk toolkit.

I've read the log file into a variable via log_file_1_raw = log_file_1.read()

I then tried using the following to split the text into sentences:

```
log_file_1_sent = re.split('^[2][0][1][6]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 : , ! \. \-]+([\\][n])$', log_file_1_raw).
```

Because the log_file_1_raw variable converts new line into \n this marks the end of a log entry and each log entry starts with an American style date.

When I run the above code I end up with the whole log as a single sentence instead of multiple sentences.

So I would appreciate it if someone could show me where I am going wrong with the regular expression as I have been stuck on this for several hours now.

Here is an excerpt of the `log_file_1_raw`, which when parsed by `re.split` is returned as a single sentence.

```
2016-11-11 08:56:12,801 INFO  mysite.co.uk.app.web.ips.controller.variables.Validator iatSYWX3SYnLrlEx0OtXPJJNun7iYe73gRtGa5G1YyIL89wmnJbg!49205849!1478850864631 - checking for each variable on page....\n
2016-11-11 08:56:12,801 INFO  mysite.co.uk.app.web.ips.controller.variables.Validator iatSYWX3SYnLrlEx0OtXPJJNun7iYe73gRtGa5G1YyIL89wmnJbg!49205849!1478850864631 - variable Name: 16691310467\n
2016-11-11 08:56:12,801 INFO  mysite.co.uk.app.web.ips.controller.variables.Validator iatSYWX3SYnLrlEx0OtXPJJNun7iYe73gRtGa5G1YyIL89wmnJbg!49205849!1478850864631 - variablesForm.getFileName: null\
```

Comment: Please format your code appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried reading the log file with readlines()

```
with open('log.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

or

```
with open('log.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: Vikash, that worked perfectly.  I'm new to both the nltk and Python. Thank you so much for your help.